# Field in Aspect injected after its first use, causing NullPointerException at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

**ABSTRACT:**

I have some initialisation operations executed in `@PostConstruct` of `@Service` `ServiceInitialiserFacsimile`. Those operations include a call to a method after whose execution an Aspect (`DoAttionalStuffAspect`) is applied.

The Aspect is instantied through aspectOf, so it is handled by the Spring Container, but unfortunately its dependencies are injected ***AFTER*** the execution of ServiceInitialiserFacsimile `@PostConstruct`, resulting in a NullPointerException.

How can I tell the Spring Container to inject first the fields in the Aspect and then instantiate the `ServiceInitialiserFacsimile` ?

I tried with an Autowired constructor for the aspect, but I think in the end AspectJ requires the no-arg constructor, so it was no help

***CODE***

This is a Sample I created in order to reproduce the issue I have in a much more complicated app. Here is the project if you want to check it out. https://github.com/alessiop86/spring3-mvc-maven-xml-hello-world

Code below:
This is the initialisation class:

```
@Component
public class ServiceInitialiserFacsimile {

    private final SampleService sampleService;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceInitialiserFacsimile(SampleService ss) {
        this.sampleService = ss;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialiseAllTheServices() {
        this.sampleService.init();
    }

}
```

This is the service with some custom logic that requires to be initialised by the `ServiceInitialiserFacsimile` `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Service
public class SampleService {

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("do some stuff");
        try {
            execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("I do not want to block to whole framework initialisation");
        }
    }

    @DoAdditionalStuff
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Phase 1");
    }
}
```

This is the annotation I use in the aspect definition

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DoAdditionalStuff {
}
```

This is the aspect

```
@Aspect
public class AdditionalStuffAspect {

    private AdditionalStuffService service;

    public AdditionalStuffService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(AdditionalStuffService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicMethod() { }

    @AfterReturning("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(doAdditionalStuff)")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint jointPoint, DoAdditionalStuff doAdditionalStuff) {
        System.out.println(jointPoint);
        service.doStuff();
    }
}
```

This is the service that is created, but not yet instantiated when the aspect is run:

```
@Service
public class AdditionalStuffService {

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Phase2: additional stuff");
    }
}
```

Spring context xml configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="initialisation.mess"/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="initialisation.mess.aspects.AdditionalStuffAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="service" ref="additionalStuffService" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: If you are using basic Spring AOP then it will never work. A proxy isn't being created yet so no AOP is applied yet, next to that if it even would be a proxy it still wouldn't work as it is an internal method call and that doesn't pass through the proxy.

Comment: If you are using LTW or CTW and have the aspect managed by Spring how should spring know what to inject... There is no `@Autowired` on the aspect for injection..

Comment: @M.Deinum I am sorry I forgot to add the xml to the question (it is available on github, I am going to add it here too).

I am using xml configuration for dependency injection because I am replicating the codebase of the much bigger project I have to update

Comment: Anyway the problem is not that aspects are not working or dependency injection are not working. Everything is working but the execution order is the wrong one

Comment: No it isn't out of order, your aspect is woven in, so it executes when needed, as there is no explicit order (that spring can detect!) you would have to specify it yourself, add a `dependsOn` on each bean that requires the aspect.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried to add a DependsOn("additionalStuffAspect") in the ServiceInitialiserFacsimile. The outcome is the same (I have tried both with and without Component in the Aspect class).

The Aspect is created (but it was also without DependsOn) before the ServiceInitialiserFacsimile's PostConstruct, but its setter for the autowired field is called after the PostConstruct.

Comment: Ok, I sorted it out, the xml configuration was overriding the Component in the aspect, so the DependsOn was picking up the wrong name. I am writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to enforce a dependency on the ServiceInitialiserFacsimile from the Aspect by setting an id in the xml:

```
  <bean id="myAspect" class="initialisation.mess.aspects.AdditionalStuffAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="service" ref="additionalStuffService" />
    </bean>
```

and then specifying the dependency of `ServiceInitialiserFacsimile` from the spring managed `AdditionalStuffAspect` with a `@DependsOn` annotation:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("myAspect")
public class ServiceInitialiserFacsimile {

    private final SampleService sampleService;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceInitialiserFacsimile(SampleService ss) {
        this.sampleService = ss;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialiseAllTheServices() {
        this.sampleService.init();
    }

}
```